# MySQL GROUP BY query

Tags: mysql

`table`-- `t_id_with_data_and_count`

`column` - `f_id , f-data , f_count`

its a many to many map `table` (any `id` can have any number of records(with `f_id` and `f_data` set being unique in nature))

`SELECT * FROM t_id_with_data_and_count where f-data IN ('PHP','JAVA') GROUP BY 1 HAVING COUNT(*)= 2 AND f_count >=17`

Expected result : i am expecting it should return me all ids who are having `php` and `java`  and  count of `php` , `java`  >= `17`

results getting now: getting all the ids with both `php` and `java` , but count it is checking for `java` only, if the count of `java` is >= 17 it throws me the result.

but i am looking for it should also check for count of `php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you group by `f_id`, `f_count` in the havinf clause has the value of either a 'PHP' or a  'JAVA' row.

What you need to check is that `f_count` is >= 17 **and also** that the sum of `f_count`s is >= (17 + the "arbitrary" `f_count`).
(In other words: If the `f_id` has both 'PHP' and 'JAVA' rows **and** one of the `f_count`s is >= 17 **and** the sum of the two `f_count`s is >= (17 + the one `f_count` (that we checked is >= 17) **then** we found a match !)

```
SELECT *
  FROM t_id_with_data_and_count
  WHERE f_data IN ('PHP', 'JAVA')
  GROUP BY f_id
  HAVING COUNT(f_id) = 2
    AND f_count >= 17
    AND SUM(f_count) >= f_count + 17
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a86f5/6)**.

Comment: SUM doesnot guarantee the individual count.. individual count of each should be >= 17

Comment: @Aditya: I updated my answer (and added a link to a short demo).

Comment: i also got it with a little diff solution posting it , so u can see that also

Answer (score 0):

Conditions on the HAVING clause will be evaluated against the values computed for the GROUPed row, not the original rows. Each non-grouped column can obviously only contain the value from one of the group members, so you cannot guarantee an universal condition through it. Therefore you need to move your comparison to the WHERE clause. But you need to specify a bit more what you want, since there are two possible interpretations.

If the `f_id` and `f_data` combination is UNIQUE there can only be at most two rows, so simply checking `f_count` in the WHERE clause is enough:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_id_with_data_and_count
WHERE f_data IN ('PHP','JAVA')
  AND f_count >= 17
GROUP BY f_id
HAVING COUNT(*);
```

Otherwise you need to specify whether you need *at least* two rows with a large enough count, or if you want *all* of the rows for an id and set of languages to have `f_count >= 17` *and* that there are at least a given number of them.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT f_id
FROM t_id_with_data_and_count
WHERE f_data
IN ('PHP','JAVA')
AND f_count >=17
GROUP  BY f_id
HAVING COUNT(  DISTINCT f_data )  = 2`